# Already existing SecurityFilterChain is preventing my configuration on Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm making a configuration on the newest Spring Security version. Based on Beans rather than the deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

I follow the Spring recomendation on configure a `Bean`for `SecurityFilterChain` and another for `WebSecurityCustomizer`

This is a Spring Boot project with MVC for a rest API.

I'm getting this error about trying to modify the `SecurityFilterChain` Bean and not being allowed to:

```
20... ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'filterChainApi' defined in class path resource [.../config/jwt/config/JWTWebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChainApi' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: 
Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@2942c1a2 to already built object
```

More StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChainApi' defined in class path resource [.../config/jwt/config/JWTWebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChainApi' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@2942c1a2 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:719) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at ....main(ManiClass.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChainApi' defined in class path resource [.../config/jwt/config/JWTWebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChainApi' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@2942c1a2 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1462) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@2942c1a2 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@2942c1a2 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@2942c1a2 to already built object
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.add(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:182) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.apply(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:138) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:119) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.authenticationManager(HttpSecurityConfiguration.java:109) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity(HttpSecurityConfiguration.java:87) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Relevant pom.xml parts:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>

<!-- ... -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- ...-->

</dependencies>
```

This gets:

- Spring v 5.3.22
- Spring boot v 2.7.3
- Spring Security 5.7.3

Spring security configuration class:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

    @Bean(name ="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApi(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http

                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .exceptionHandling(configurer ->
                    configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .headers(headersConfigurer -> {
                    headersConfigurer.cacheControl();             // disable caching
                    headersConfigurer.frameOptions().sameOrigin();// H2 Console Needs this setting
                })
               .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .build();
    }

//    @Bean // I don't declare this until I see the other one working.
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(... )
                .antMatchers(...)
                .antMatchers(...)
                
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider userDetailsAuthProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider a = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        a.setUserDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService);
        a.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager( AuthenticationManagerBuilder amb) throws Exception {
        return amb.authenticationProvider(userDetailsAuthProvider()).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation?

Comment: `SpringSecurityConfiguration` missing `@Configuration`! (In post only..or indeed?:) (Yes, EnableWebSecurity is (only) documented with `@Configuration`..)

Comment: @grekier didn't work.

Comment: @xerx593  Isn't it included inside @EnableWebSecurity?

Comment: Nope, it isn't.https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.java and javadoc clearly states: "add this annotation to..."

Comment: It imports configurations (for this to work, it should be a configuration), but it is none implicitly..

Comment: ..and since it is (among others) HttpSecurityConfiguration, which should be/failed to import, the error message becomes more comprehendable

Comment: By the way I was trying to solve this with and without the @Configuration the basis of the problem was the one explained in the 2 first answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem with `AuthenticationManager` bean.
If you don't use it anywhere, just try to remove it, because spring-boot will create it automatically applying your defined `AuthenticationProvider` bean (with your custom `PasswordEncoder` and `UserDetailsService`).

If you need `AuthenticationManager` elsewhere (e.g. injected in a `Filter`), change your bean definition to the following:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

The reason is in the new spring-security `AuthenticationManager` is already created with the desired parameters when you're trying to inject AuthenticationManagerBuilder, so you can't configure it again.

Also you don't even need to define a `AuthenticationProvider` bean, because `DaoAuthenticationProvider` is the default provider which is used if a `UserDetailsService` bean found in the context, and it also automatically will utilize your `PasswordEncoder` bean.

Edit: this way of creating the `AuthenticationManager` bean can lead to unexpected behaviors, like StackOverflowError, please [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694980/authenticationmanager-authenticate-throws-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null-w/74706573#74706573) for a better way to do that

Comment: This is the one that worked. I still have have some problem to discern what things is doing Spring boot behind the scene

Comment: @AntonioE. in Intellij IDEA you can always CTRL + click on the class name and look if it's mentioned in some `...AutoConfiguration` class of spring-boot - the code there will help you understand what spring-boot does and in what cases

Answer (score 5):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@2942c1a2 to already built object
```

Spring Security is telling you that you cannot apply a new configurer to the already built object (`HttpSecurity`). Often times you should not need an `AuthenticationManager`.

If you really want to expose an `AuthenticationManager` do it by yourself instead of using the `AuthenticationConfiguration`. Instead of doing:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager( AuthenticationManagerBuilder amb) throws Exception {
        return amb.authenticationProvider(userDetailsAuthProvider()).build();
}
```

You can do:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(userDetailsAuthProvider());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it gave me a good context for the problem.

Comment: Using your suggestion worked for me, any reason why we cannot use `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` or `AuthenticationConfiguration`? Would love to read more about it.