# AuthenticationManager.authenticate() throws java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when just creating another class that implements AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, basic-authentication

In my project, I have two different authentication paths: the first one for normal user login and the second for employer login. So I begin by creating an authentication filter for the user using its AuthenticationProvider, and it works fine. For the second authentication, I create its authentication filter, and when I create another authentication provider for the employer, that is the problem. I get a **java.lang.StackOverflowError: null** when I try to authenticate the user's username and password using an instance of **AuthenticationManager** in **authenticationmanager.authenticate(userPassAuthToken)**.

I didn't understand what happened when I created another authentication provider or why the authentication manager threw this exception. I think that the authentication manager is confused about which provider to use.

At first, I create the first authentication for a normal user with its filter and authentication provider as shown in the following code:

1. User Filter class

```
@Component
public class UserPassAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;
    @Autowired
    private AuthPath authPath;
    @Autowired
    AuthFilterUtil authFilterUtil;
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        char[] username=request.getHeader("username").toCharArray();
        char[] password=request.getHeader("password").toCharArray();

        UserPassAuthToken authentication= new UserPassAuthToken(String.valueOf(username),String.valueOf(password));
        UserPassAuthToken currentAuth =(UserPassAuthToken)authManager.authenticate(authentication);
        if (!currentAuth.isAuthenticated()){
            authFilterUtil.onFailureAuth(response,request,null);
        }
        else {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(currentAuth);
            if(request.getServletPath().equals(authPath.getUserPasswordFilter_pathShouldDo().get(0))) {
                UserDto responseBody = userMapper.mapUserToDto(currentAuth.getUsersDetails().getUsers());
                responseBody.setToken(authFilterUtil.prepareTokenToAuthResponse(
                        currentAuth.getAuthorities(),
                        currentAuth.getName().toCharArray()
                ));
                authFilterUtil.onSuccessfulAuth(response, responseBody);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {

        return !authPath.getUserPasswordFilter_pathShouldDo().contains(request.getServletPath());
    }
}
```

2. user Authentication token class

```
public class UserPassAuthToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private UsersDetails usersDetails;

    public UserPassAuthToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(principal, credentials);
    }

    public UserPassAuthToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
    }
}
```

3. user authentication provider class

```
@Component
public class UserPassAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    UserService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserPassAuthToken authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username =authentication.getName();
        String password=(String)authentication.getCredentials();

        UserPassAuthToken userPassAuthToken;
        UsersDetails   user=userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (user !=null && password != null && passwordEncoder.matches(password,user.getPassword())){
            userPassAuthToken=new UserPassAuthToken(username,user.getPassword(),user.getAuthorities());
            userPassAuthToken.setUsersDetails(user);
        }else {
            userPassAuthToken = new UserPassAuthToken(username, password);
            userPassAuthToken.setAuthenticated(false);
        }
        userPassAuthToken = new UserPassAuthToken(username, password);
        userPassAuthToken.setAuthenticated(false);
        return userPassAuthToken;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authType) {
        return UserPassAuthToken.class.equals(authType);
    }
}
```

4. employer authentication provider class

```
@Component
public class EmployerAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    EmployerService employerService;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public EmployerPassAuthToken authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        char[]username =authentication.getName().toCharArray();
        char[] password=(char[]) authentication.getCredentials();
        EmployerPassAuthToken employerPassAuthToken;
        UsersDetails employer=employerService.loadUserByUsername(String.valueOf(username));
        if (employer !=null && password != null && passwordEncoder.matches(String.valueOf(password),employer.getPassword())){
            employerPassAuthToken=new EmployerPassAuthToken(username,employer.getPassword(),employer.getAuthorities());
            employerPassAuthToken.setUsersDetails(employer);
        }else {
            employerPassAuthToken = new EmployerPassAuthToken(username, password);
            employerPassAuthToken.setAuthenticated(false);
        }
        return employerPassAuthToken;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authType) {
        return EmployerPassAuthToken.class.equals(authType);
    }
}
```

5. security configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class SecConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserPassAuthProvider userPassAuthProvider;
    @Autowired
    UserPassAuthFilter userPassAuthFilter;
    @Autowired
    TokenAuthFilter tokenAuthFilter;
    @Autowired
    AuthPathPrivilege userPrivilege;
    @Autowired
    AuthPath authPath;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(authPath.getAllNotAuthPath().iterator().next()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(authPath.getAllAuthPath().iterator().next()).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(userPrivilege.getSuper_adminPrivilegePath().iterator().next()).hasAnyAuthority("SUPER_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(userPrivilege.getAdminPrivilegePath().iterator().next()).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(userPrivilege.getManagerPrivilegePath().iterator().next()).hasAnyAuthority("MANAGER")
                .antMatchers(userPrivilege.getUserPrivilegePath().iterator().next()).hasAnyAuthority("USER")
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and().authenticationProvider(userPassAuthProvider)
                .addFilterAt(userPassAuthFilter , BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(tokenAuthFilter , BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

**Note: **

1. Also using Intellij idea debugging it stuck on the same line of code **authManager.authenticate(authentication)** in user filter class
2. The application didn't enter user authentication provider after creating employer provider.

Comment: Getting the `AuthenticationManager` from the `AuthenticationConfiguration` is not best practice. Instead you should get the `AuthenticationManager` in a custom DSL and pass it to the custom Filter, as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509142/passing-authenticationmanager-to-custom-filter/72528280#72528280

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I have a similar issue but I couldn't have any idea how to fix it. Can you help me? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633891/spring-boot-microservices-spring-security-servicetest-and-controllertest-for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to Eleftheria's comment:

You are asking Spring Security to provide you an `AuthenticationManager` bean by calling `authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()`.

1. The `AuthenticationConfiguration` calls the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to create the `AuthenticationManager`, and it only creates the `AuthenticationManager` if there is [**only one** `AuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/InitializeAuthenticationProviderBeanManagerConfigurer.java) or [**only one** `UserDetailsService`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer.java) configured. If it is not able to create it, then [a lazy initialization bean will be provided](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/03438ffc0344eded3923548283a228f8eae5fbe4/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/AuthenticationConfiguration.java#L123).
2. When the application tries to use the `AuthenticationManager` for the first time, the lazy initialization bean will be triggered, invoking the method that creates the bean, which in your case is:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

3. That method, in turn, invokes `AuthenticationConfiguration#getAuthenticationManager` which will return a lazy initialization bean again since the `AuthenticationManager` cannot be created because of <1>, and the cycle continues.

So, why Spring Security didn't initialize the `AuthenticationManager` in your case? Because you have 2 `AuthenticationProvider`s, and there is no way for Spring Security to know how you want to combine them, that's why Spring Security backs off and lets you deal with the creation of `AuthenticationManager`.

**How do you fix it?**

Since Spring Security cannot create the bean for you, you would have to create the `AuthenticationManager` bean yourself. Here is how to do that in your scenario:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> myAuthenticationProviders) {
    return new ProviderManager(myAuthenticationProviders);
}
```

For folks that want to use a `UserDetailsService`, you can create a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and set the necessary fields.

Comment: Thanks alot. Gboza for the man wey sabi! (just hailed you in Nigerian pidgin) Although, why try to initialize lazily? and not throwing a more precise exception?

Comment: Spring Security cannot create an instance of `AuthenticationManager` at the time the `AuthenticationConfiguration` is being processed since this process happens very early on the bean initialization stage, therefore there could be problems with the `AuthenticationManager` dependencies.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Please, I am facing a similar spring security challenge and need your knowledge to fix it urgently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75858524/issue-with-two-jwt-authentication-filters-in-spring-boot-security

Comment: Your fix doesn't involve `http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class)` so it seems Eleftheria's comment isn't relevant. This did fix my issue though.