# Issue with two JWT Authentication filters (Spring Boot security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm writing this Spring Boot application which requires two security filter chains and two JWT authentication filters, and I can't get things to work smoothly after implementing all I currently know.

One of the entities:

`Affiliate.java` class

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Affiliate implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String sex;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    @Column(name = "balance_in_naira")
    private int balance;
    private String referralCode;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role = Role.AFFILIATE;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Student> students;

    private boolean enabled;

    public void increaseBalance(int referralBonus) {
        balance += referralBonus;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + getRole().name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

The security configuration:

`SecurityConfig.java`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final StudentJwtAuthorizationFilter studentJwtAuthorizationFilter;
    private final StudentDetailsService studentDetailsService;
    private final AffiliateDetailsService affiliateDetailsService;
    private final AffiliateJwtAuthorizationFilter affiliateJwtAuthorizationFilter;

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain affiliateFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                   .securityMatcher("/api/affiliates", "/api/affiliates/**")
                   .cors().disable()
                   .csrf().disable()
                   .formLogin().disable()
                   .httpBasic().disable()
                   .authorizeHttpRequests()
                       .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/affiliates").permitAll()
                       .requestMatchers("/api/affiliates/confirm", "/api/affiliates/auth", "/api/affiliates/forgot-password", "/api/affiliates/forgot-password/**").permitAll()
                       .requestMatchers("/api/affiliates", "/api/affiliates/referrals").hasRole(Role.AFFILIATE.name())
                       .anyRequest().authenticated()
                       .and()
                   .authenticationProvider(affiliateAuthenticationProvider())
                   .addFilterBefore(affiliateJwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                   .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain studentFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                   .securityMatcher("/api/students", "/api/students/**")
                   .cors().disable()
                   .csrf().disable()
                   .httpBasic().disable()
                   .formLogin().disable()
                   .authorizeHttpRequests()
                       .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/students").permitAll()
                       .requestMatchers("/api/students/auth", "/api/students/forgot-password", "/api/students/forgot-password/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/students/confirm").permitAll()
                       .requestMatchers("/api/students/complete-registration").hasRole(Role.STUDENT.name())
                       .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/students").hasRole(Role.STUDENT.name())
                       .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/students").hasRole(Role.STUDENT.name())
                       .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/api/students/new-password").hasRole(Role.STUDENT.name())
                       .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/students").hasRole(Role.STUDENT.name())
                       .anyRequest().authenticated()
                       .and()
                   .authenticationProvider(studentAuthenticationProvider())
                   .addFilterBefore(studentJwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                   .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider studentAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(studentDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider affiliateAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(affiliateDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders) throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders);
    }
}
```

The first filter;

`AffiliateJwtAuthorizationFilter.java`

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AffiliateJwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final AffiliateDetailsService detailsService;
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authValue != null && authValue.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String token = authValue.substring(7);
            Affiliate affiliate = detailsService.loadUserByUsername(jwtService.extractUsername(token));
            if (!jwtService.isExpired(token)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(affiliate, null, affiliate.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

                response.setHeader("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization"));
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The second filter:

`StudentJwtAuthorizationFilter.java`

```java
@Component //make this a bean
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentJwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final StudentDetailsService detailsService;
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authValue != null && authValue.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String token = authValue.substring(7);
            Student student = detailsService.loadUserByUsername(jwtService.extractUsername(token));
            if (!jwtService.isExpired(token)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(student, null, student.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

               response.setHeader("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization")); //Check whether this is
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Using Postman, when I hit HTTP `GET` against `/api/affiliates` with an authenticated Bearer token, I get a 403 response.

See the request handler:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/affiliates")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AffiliateController {
    private final AffiliateService affiliateService;

    @GetMapping
    public AffiliateDto get() {
        return affiliateService.get();
    }
}
```

I am expecting an OK status, not ‘forbidden’. What can I try next?

Comment: One way to troubleshoot this issue would be to enable debugging for Spring Security and check the logs to see which rules are being applied to the request and why access is being denied. You could also try removing some of the more specific rules (such as .requestMatchers("/api/affiliates/confirm", "/api/affiliates/auth", "/api/affiliates/forgot-password", "/api/affiliates/forgot-password/**").permitAll()) to see if they are conflicting with the more general .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/affiliates").permitAll() rule.

Comment: .requestMatchers("/api/affiliates", "/api/affiliates/referrals").hasRole(Role.AFFILIATE.name())

This states that your api  /api/affiliates and /api/affiliates/referrals require the AFFILIATE role.

Comment: According to the rules of Spring security, there isn't supposed to be any conflict associated with the endpoints, that's why I don't want to begin changing things. And, every affiliate who registers is automatically assigned an AFFILIATE role as hardcoded in the Affiliate entity.

Comment: this is not the way how to handle JWTs in spring security. Please read the spring security documentation on how to acctually handle JWTs correctly and safely by using the built in JWT features of spring security. Both these filters are unnecassary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot will automatically register any bean that is a Filter. This means that both of your filters will be added to each of your two filter chains, which you probably do not want to. To avoid that you can either not to expose your filters as beans and only register them with Spring Security, or you can tell Spring Boot not to register your beans as filters, like this:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration1(AffiliateJwtAuthorizationFilter filter) {
    return createFilterRegistration(filter);
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registration2(StudentJwtAuthorizationFilter filter) {
    return createFilterRegistration(filter);
}

private FilterRegistrationBean createFilterRegistration(Filter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the an answer that i didn’t just copy and paste, but understood. Cheers!