# Why does Autowired AuthenticationManager throw StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to make a spring boot application with JWT security. I want to use Spring Security's AuthenticationManager for authentication. I create a AuthenticationManager Bean in my Configuration Class and Autowire this in my RestController class. But when I want to use the AuthenticationManager I get an StackOverflowError.

My Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @GetMapping("/sign-in")
    public String signIn() {
        System.out.println(authenticationManager);
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

My Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JwtConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/sign-in").permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The error I get when i am doing a GET request to /sign-in:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.toString(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:211) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.toString(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:211) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.toString(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:211) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.toString(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
```

etc.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter , https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11926 (+ linked)

Comment: Please try (I'm mobile): remove the `@Bean` (but still try to auto-wire it)

Comment: this seems to be your problem [AuthenticationManager.authenticate() throws java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when just creating another class that implements AuthenticationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694980/authenticationmanager-authenticate-throws-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you suggestions. I added a Controller class and put the following code in it:

```
@Autowired
HttpSecurity httpSecurity;
@Autowired
UserService userService;
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
        .userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        .and()
        .build();
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove:

```
System.out.println(authenticationManager);
```

As it seems to be called recursively and cause the problem (see the line `$Proxy58.toString(Unknown Source)` ).
If you want to make sure it is called, just put a simple string, or better yet, use the debugger.

Comment: I want to use the AuthenticationManager to do something like`authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()));`
When I do, I still get a StackOverflowError