# AuthenticationManager.authenticate method causing stackoverflow in springBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following config file:

```
package com.example.demo.security;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private JwtAuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint;
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService, JwtAuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.authEntryPoint = authEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public  JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JWTAuthenticationFilter();
    }
}
```

However, `the authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();` returns null as authenticationConfiguration has no authenticationManager and it didn't get initialized either, however, I'm not sure if that's the problem. Anyway, if I try to call its authenticate method, it gives me a stack overflow error. Why's that?

I'm using the method here:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private JWTGenerator jwtGenerator;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository,
                          RoleRepository roleRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, JWTGenerator jwtGenerator) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody User user){
        Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user.getUsername(),
                        user.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String token = jwtGenerator.generateToken(authentication);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AuthenticationManager.authenticate() throws java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when just creating another class that implements AuthenticationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694980/authenticationmanager-authenticate-throws-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null-w)

Answer (score 0):

try overriding configure method with AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth input and delete UserDetails and AuthenticationManager authenticationManager bean in your config